# Data prediction from previous data history using AI/ML

Tags: machine-learning, automation, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for solutions where I can automatically approve or disapprove different supplier invoices based on historical data.

Let's say, I got an invoice from an HP laptop supplier and based on the previous data, I have to approve or reject that invoice.

Basically, I want to make a decision or prediction based on the data already available based on the history with artificial intelligence, machine learning or any other cloud service

Comment: well start doing then. i'm sure you can understand that your question has no question in it and thus we can not answer it. Please take the time to read the how to ask part of the SO tutos.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys but I am looking for solution where I can make predication based on previous data in AI or ML. I am new to this but just want to get started with this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct question though but you can start by looking into various methods of classifications. There is a huge amount of material available online. Try reading about K-Nearest Neighbors, Naive Bayes, K-means, etc. to get an idea about how algorithms in Machine Learning domain work. Once you start understanding what is written in the documentation then start implementing them. You will face a lot of problems which you can search online and I'm sure you will find most of them answered here in this portal.